Swf unloads, but AS3 within that swf still executes
I have an AS3 Air App (Desktop App)- let us call it MAIN that loads a bunch of swfs. So, MAIN loads swfA and then unloads it. MAIN has an event listener that listens to unloading of swfA. Trace shows swfA is unloaded successfully, as the unload event fires. However, the as3 contained within swfA still executes long after swfA is unloaded. How do I know? There is a timer-event in swfA that still executes even though swfA has been unloaded.
Is this a feature or is my code missing anything.
Here is basic code in MAIN
swfLoader.load(new URLRequest("swfA")); // load the SWF file                 
swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onSwfLoad);                  
swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.UNLOAD, onSwfUnload);

Here is basic code in swfA
var timer: Timer = new Timer(1000, 60);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimeUp);
timer.start();

The desired behavior for the swf to unload and all that ActionScript3 to NOT execute, as unloading the swf, well my understanding of it at least, is that it is unloaded, gone, not here! Thanks for any insight on the matter!

I think you need to investigate LoaderContext: https://www.cs.vu.nl/~eliens/assets/flex3/langref/flash/system/LoaderContext.html I suspect that you load external SWFs into the same security/application domain as the main one, and thus they all operate in the same sadnbox and when the external one uses Timer class it is as if the main one does. Try putting them into different application domains. Alternately, you may just write a destroy method that completely unsubscribes/removes/dismantles everything that is done by the loaded SWFs (which is actually a good practice itself).

@Organis Thanks a lot for the explanation and the answer. This makes a lot of sense. I will do that

Upon having any result please share it. Might worth forming a real answer while I still remember anything.

still investigating and testing applicationDomain. Will report back. Thanks!

So, nothing to report after a few tries. However, I came across this question on the stack and it might help me figure it out. Posting it just for reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752053/applicationdomain-clarifiation-needed

OK, I figured a workaround (not the cleanest way), but does the job. Since Main.swf can pass parameters to loaded swfA, swfA listens to parameter change from Main and then once that change happens (when Main passes that info via context parameters to SwfA, SwfA has a function in it that stops all code. The other option that I tried was to load an empty no code Swf in place of swfA, but that did not get me what I wanted.

Well, as long as you figured that out : )

I am providing an updated answer that best worked for me, and I stumbled upon it while I was troublehshooting something else. It turned out that the answer was super easy. Posting answer in case this might be helpful to someone in the future.
It turns out, in AS3, one can use the following method which unloads the swf, AND stops the loaded swf from executing anything in it. This worked for me! I was using the
    loader.unload()

When I should have been using the
    loader.unloadAndStop(true); 

